# Getting list of values out of list of objects

Tags: c#, linq

I have a simple class:

```
 private class Category
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

an also a list of objects of this type:

```
 List<Category> Categories;
```

I need to get a list of Ids that are in Categories list. Is there a simpler way to do this than using for loop like this:

```
 List<int> list = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < Categories.Count; i++)
    {
        list.Add(Categories[i].Id);
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

This expression gives you the list you want:

```cs
    Categories.Select(c => c.Id).ToList();
```

Also, don't forget

```cs
    using System.Linq;
```

Answer (score 16):

Use as follows.

```
Categories.Select(c => c.Id).ToList();
```

||

```
List<int> list = new List<int>();
foreach (Category item in Categories)
{
    list.Add(item.Id);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```cs
Categories.Select(c => c.Id).ToList();
```

Gives a list of lists (`List<List<Id>>`).

```cs
Categories.SelectMany(c => c.Id).ToList();
```

Returns only a list of `Id`s.